# We need a 'close as dup' button to go with the new LQ review of links to existing answers

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

Recently, the system started loading the LQ Queue with answers consisting of links to other questions and answers.

Gosh it would be efficient if I could cast a close-as-duplicate right there in the review, instead of needing to go through extra clicks to haul up the question and vote to close it.